# Importar proyecto en NetBeans con otra version diferente a la de mi pc

Tags: java

Utilice NetBeans en otra pc que no tiene la misma version que mi pc y cuando intento importar mi proyecto lo importa bien pero no me sale la pestaña de diseño solo source si lo ejecuto ejecuta bien lo que llevo hasta ahora.

Comment: Que errores obtienes en la consola?

Comment: A que te refieres con "pestaña de diseño" estas desarrollando alguna interfaz gráfica con swing?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba abrirlo en otra Pc puede que el proyecto se haya copiado mal. A mí me ha pasado eso pero cuando uso librerías por ejemplo cuando uso JCalendar y la nueva pc no lo tiene no aparecen los elementos de la librería que no tiene la pc.